# ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-angular" but i'm not using Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

i'm working on a React application using ES6. The application was created using the `create-react-app` wrapper.

I'm setting up the ESLint for that application but i'm getting the error `ESLint couldn't find the plugin eslint-plugin-angular`. The thing is that **i'm not using Angular anywhere** as far as i know. Did you ever have an error like this?

Could be that the angular plugin is being required for some reason i'm not considering?

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "repo"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.7.1",
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.26.0",
    "detect-port": "1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint": "3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "filesize": "3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "gzip-size": "3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.2",
    "jest": "17.0.2",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "path-exists": "2.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.0.0",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.1",
    "recursive-readdir": "2.1.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "strip-ansi": "3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "inuitcss": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>[/\\\\](build|docs|node_modules)[/\\\\]"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ]
    }
}
```

And my `babel.rc` file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

Did you guys have this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like [this might be a similar problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/71). Is there a .eslinrc file in your user folder? You could try removing it or installing the plugins globally. If this solves your problem, tell me and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah! You got it right. There was another .eslintrc file in my Desktop folder. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it! Could you please accept my answer below? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [this might be a similar problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/71). Is there a .eslinrc in your user folder? You could try removing it or installing the plugins globally.